# C# class declaration "from metadata"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I've noticed in Visual Studio some classes have an option that if you look at their definition, you don't actually see the definition only the class's declaration and some documentation, for example: [image]

Does anyone know how to make my classes lead to a similar file?
Thanks

Comment: Move your required classes to a different assembly(dll) and refer this dll from your application will do.

Comment: you can not see implementation because of you are browsing external assembly, you need to decompile it firstly. I believe this is good explanation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the default behavior if Visual Studio can't find the PDB file which contains information on the location of the actual file and the line numbers in the compiled code.

This should work if you include a referenced assembly from another solution, and then rename the folder where the code is contained. Remove the PDB from the referenced location, and you will see this outline.

For you as a developer, showing the code is a feature: it helps you to debug and analyse problems in assemblies you have built. So I would advice to keep it on. Don't worry too much about other developers, if you don't send the PDB file, they won't see the code from Visual Studio. They still can read the assembly's source code using Reflector for example.

Answer (score 10):

I think some basic has to be explained here.

- **Source code** is bunch of C# files (.cs). This is where code of your classes is
- When you **compile** source code you will get an **assembly** (.dll). Assembly contains **metadata** about your classes and compiled binary code, but not actual source code.
- When you **compile** your source code, Visual Studio produces also **.PDB file** along with your assembly. PDB files allows you to see the source code of the assembly. PDB files are necessary for debugging. It is somewhat similar to javascript source maps.

---

Now, when in Visual Studio you **Go to Definition** of a class or a method , then following can happen:

1. The class is in your solution `->` you are navigated to the source code file (.cs)
2. The class is defined in a referenced assembly and PDB file is available `->`  you are navigated to source code extracted from the PDB file. You can debug it, (however, you cannot edit it).
3. The class is defined in a references assembly and PDB file is NOT available `->` you are navigated the assembly metadata. *(this is what happend on the picture you've posted)*

So answer to your question is: isolate your assembly from .PDB and source code. However, you should be aware, that there are tools, that can reverse engineer C# code from the binary code that is in the assembly. It will be not exactly the same as your original source code but very similar.